# The virtual machine does not see the iso image

Tags: virtualbox, iso

I currently installed the virtual machine on VirtualBox, but it looks like the machine can't see the .iso image. After running the machine I get "No bootable medium found! System halted". I have found out that there might not be an iso image inserted in the virtual optical device and it could be the matter. When the iso image was chosen in the folder option, the error still stays. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Can you check that your Virtualbox System has an DVD/CD drive installed in it (Under Settings -> Storage) and when you're in there, if you click on the optical drive, and then the CD image at the right hand side of the drive, can you see if your ISO is loaded?

Comment: On the right hand side of the table I see the icon of the optical disk, but there is no path to the .iso.

Comment: If the ISO is not being loaded by VirtualBox, then the file may be incomplete 

Comment: This seems more like a "how do I use virtualbox" question than an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Matigo, the imadge I used was the second one, but I am going to make a checksumm test.

Comment: Most issues with `virtualbox` need to be corrected on your HOST OS (*you didn't specify any*) on the Virtual Box program itself; ie. unrelated to the ISO you're trying to boot.  Usually you specify an ISO on the host OS virtualbox configuration/settings; however you can still have virtualbox boot an ISO that was written to thumb-drive (again this is setup by host OS virtualbox settings). You gave no specifics as to where ISO is located (written to bootable media which is inserted; does it boot on real hardware - ie. is bootable?) or as ISO file (where problem is config on HOST OS config)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by selecting IDE-controller, the optical device option, and selecting the ISO image in the folder.

Thanks!